# Problem deleting rows using left outer join in mysql

Tags: mysql

Cant seem to workout what im doing wrong here

`SELECT * FROM tbl_imagelabel LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_image ON tbl_imagelabel.label_id = tbl_image.label_id WHERE tbl_image.label_id is NULL`

shows the exact rows I want to delete. but if i change SELECT * FROM to DELETE FROM it doesnt work

`DELETE FROM tbl_imagelabel LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_image ON tbl_imagelabel.label_id = tbl_image.label_id WHERE tbl_image.label_id is NULL`

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` in front of the `DELETE` query and paste the output here.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "doesnt work"? Is there any error message given?

Answer (score 12):

For futher reference, on MySQL 5+:

```
DELETE tbl1.* FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 USING(fld) WHERE tbl2.fld IS NULL;
```

It'll delete any orphans on ***TBL1*** using ***fld*** as join.

GL
Paulo Bueno

Answer (score 10):

You're trying to delete from multiple tables in a single query with that syntax. Try something more like (and this is just a loose example, not meant to be optimized or anything):

```
DELETE FROM tbl_imagelabel
WHERE label_id IN (
    SELECT tbl_imagelabel.label_id 
    FROM tbl_imagelabel 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_image 
        ON tbl_imagelabel.label_id = tbl_image.label_id 
    WHERE tbl_image.label_id IS NULL
)
```

Comment: 34 seconds make all the difference :-)

Comment: LoL... I know... +1 for the solution either way :D

Comment: happy to return the favor :-)

Comment: When I try to run a query using a similar tactic using PHPmyAdmin, it gives me a message that I can't include the table I am deleting from int he WHERE clause. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

I believe this does the same thing without the explicit join.

```
DELETE FROM tbl_imagelabel 
WHERE label_id NOT IN (SELECT label_id FROM tbl_image)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM tbl_imagelabel 
where label_id IN
(
SELECT tbl_imagelabel.label_id FROM tbl_imagelabel 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_image 
ON tbl_imagelabel.label_id = tbl_image.label_id WHERE tbl_image.label_id is NULL
)
```

assuming that label_id is the unique primary key.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst all the answers given here provide alternative means of solving the specific example given in the question, they all do so without actually including a left outer join explicitly in the delete statement.  To do that, you need the 'USING' statement as follows:

```
DELETE FROM til USING tbl_imagelabel as til LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_image as ti 
ON til.label_id = ti.label_id WHERE ti.label_id is NULL
```

**References:**

- http://donauweb.at/ebusiness-blog/2008/01/21/delete-from-mysql-with-outer-join/

Answer (score 0):

I used this Query here to delete orphan data:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE idtable1=idtable2)
```